# How to add compression option in right-click menu?

Tags: 20.04, configuration, nautilus-actions

In my Ubuntu 20.04 I lost the compression option from the right click drop-down menu.  How can I recover/add it again easily?

I have zip & unzip packages. So I can do using Terminal.  The right click option for .zip was there a few weeks ago. But now it is not there.

Instead I used B1 Free Archiver. But I need 'compress' in the right-click option.

Comment: Not sure about your question. It comes out of the box in the files view. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you have zip, 7z installed?

Comment: `Compress...` will only appear if you right click a folder in Nautilus first

Comment: did you remove nautilus-sendto?

Comment: @jpbrain: No. That package is there.

Comment: Hi AG. I am trying to reproduce the situation but I haven't been able to do it. I'll keep looking. Also, using synaptic pakage installer you will find serveral script an addons helpers for nautilus.